# Media query not working, hiding Bootstrap jumbotron when viewed from mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

can't get media query to work, trying to hide jumbotron when viewed from mobile device.

url tyrescanner.net
code below

```css
  /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
  @media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
        .customjumbotron{
            background-color: black;
        }
    }
```

```html
        <div class="row no-container">
            <div class="col-md-12">        
                <div class="jumbotron text-center customjumbotron">                
                    <img class="img-responsive image-center" src="../Images/Nectar-CollectPoints.png" height="130" width="490" style= "margin-bottom: -10px"" />
                    <h2>Search for tyres and prices in your local area</h2>                                              
                    <div class="searchbox">
                       <div class="input-group input-group-lg">           
                         <div class="input-btn-toolbar" style="width:107%; height: 100%;">                                                         
                            <div class="input-btn-toolbar" style=" background-color:#313131; padding-left:5px; padding-top:7px; padding-bottom:3px; padding-right:3px;">                                                                    
                              <asp:TextBox style="text-transform: uppercase; width:100%; font-size: 23px; text-align: center;" ID="txtReg" class="form-control"  runat="server" placeholder="Enter Registration"></asp:TextBox>                                             
                                 <span class="input-group-btn" >                                                          
                                    <asp:LinkButton class ="btn btn-default btn-default1" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click"  height="49"  runat="server" type="button" style="color:white" ID="bntSearch"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                                 </span>
                           </div>    
                        </div>    
                     </div>    
                  </div>  
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have it showing on screens with a max-width of 380px right now... don't you want it to only show on screens with a larger width?

Comment: I have change it to min-width: 380px I also have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> within the header

Comment: All your media query is doing is applying the black background.  Should it be hiding anything for smaller screens?

Comment: Sorry, I’m trying to replace the jumbotron image with a black background when viewed from mobile devices.

Comment: Ah, okay, got it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To make the jumbotron appear as a black background on small screens, add `color: black;` to your media query.  That way, everything in the jumbotron will appear black (though there are probably much more elegant ways to do it).

Working example:

```css
  /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
  @media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
        .customjumbotron{
            background-color: black;
            color: black;
        }
        #imgID {
            display: none;
        }
        #imgHide {
            display: block;
        }
    }

  /* Larger Devices */ 
  @media screen and (min-width: 381px) {
        #imgHide {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

```html
        <div class="row no-container">
            <div class="col-md-12">        
                <div class="jumbotron text-center customjumbotron">                
                    <img class="img-responsive image-center" id="imgID" src="../Images/Nectar-CollectPoints.png" height="130" width="490" style="margin-bottom: -10px" />
                    <img class="img-responsive image-center" id="imgHide" src="" height="130" width="490" style="margin-bottom: -10px"></div>
                    <h2>Search for tyres and prices in your local area</h2>                                              
                    <div class="searchbox">
                       <div class="input-group input-group-lg">           
                         <div class="input-btn-toolbar" style="width:107%; height: 100%;">                                                         
                            <div class="input-btn-toolbar" style=" background-color:#313131; padding-left:5px; padding-top:7px; padding-bottom:3px; padding-right:3px;">                                                                    
                              <asp:TextBox style="text-transform: uppercase; width:100%; font-size: 23px; text-align: center;" ID="txtReg" class="form-control"  runat="server" placeholder="Enter Registration"></asp:TextBox>                                             
                                 <span class="input-group-btn" >                                                          
                                    <asp:LinkButton class ="btn btn-default btn-default1" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click"  height="49"  runat="server" type="button" style="color:white" ID="bntSearch"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                                 </span>
                           </div>    
                        </div>    
                     </div>    
                  </div>  
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Now hides the image in the jumbotron for small screens.

Comment: @Tom If this isn't what you're looking for, can you clarify what else you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have added the color to the css, but it's still not working!

Comment: Yes this exactly what I'm looking for, but it's not working... When I view the page from a mobile device the jumbotron image is still being displayed instead of just a black background :/(

Comment: @Tom  Try it now. Hides the image on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

I fund the problem, I had to add another Media query to the Jumbotrom

```html
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .customjumbotron {
        /*.jumbotron*/
        background: url('../Images/Tyre.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        min-height: 410px;
        min-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about everything between 380px and 992px?

Comment: Thanks freginold, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

First identify what kind of iPhone you need to make it hide read [iPhone 6 Screen Size and Web Design Tips](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/iphone-6-screen-size-web-design-tips/) first. Then use the points of **different iPhone versions** to add value for **max-width or min-width** to create changes, you can use **either of the two**. But take note of other devices breakpoints not only iPhone if you add breakpoints of more than one iPhone version breakpoints. I use in the sample codes below the minimum width of the largest iPhone version in order for your design make changes for all iPhone easily, but it depends:

USING LARGEST iPHONE VERSION MINIMUM POINTS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  /* iPhone 6/7 Plus | 414 x 736 points */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 414px) {
       body{
        background-color: teal;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }
</style>
```

USING iPHONE VERSION MAX-WIDTH:

```
<style type="text/css">

    /* iPhone 4 | 320 x 480 points */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
       body{
        background-color: gold;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }

    /* iPhone 5 | 320 x 568 points */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 568px) {
       body{
        background-color: silver;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }

    /* iPhone 6/7 | 375 x 667 points */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 667px) {
       body{
        background-color: teal;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }

    /* iPhone 6/7 Plus | 414 x 736 points */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 736) {
       body{
        background-color: teal;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }
</style>
```

USING DIFFERENT iPHONE VERSION MIN-WIDTH:

```
<style type="text/css">

    /* iPhone 4 | 320 x 480 points */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
       body{
        background-color: gold;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }

    /* iPhone 5 | 320 x 568 points */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
       body{
        background-color: silver;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }

    /* iPhone 6/7 | 375 x 667 points */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 375px) {
       body{
        background-color: teal;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }

    /* iPhone 6/7 Plus | 414 x 736 points */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 414px) {
       body{
        background-color: teal;
       }
       .customjumbotron{
          display: none;
       }
    }
</style>
```

DEFAULT BOOTSTRAP MEDIA QUERIES

```
<style type="text/css">
/*==================================================
          Bootstrap 3 Media Queries
==================================================*/

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
       body{
        background-color: black;
       }
    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
       body{
        background-color: blue;
       }
    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
         /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES| SET HERE WHAT YOU NEED TO HIDE OR ANYTHING*/
       body{
        background-color: green;
       }
    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE*/
    }
</style>
```